# 404- when I deploy springboot app with additional JSP in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

```
spring boot version:1.5.9v
tomcat version: 8.5.20
```

I built a project with two pages and deployed in tomcat server. It is working fine.For the next build, I added two additional JSPs to my project with some ajax calls. When I deploy the project and executing ajax call, then its returning 404 to new pages(not hitting the REST controller methods).

When I rename the war file to ROOT.war and deploy, its working perfectly but when I keep project name as it is then its throwing 404 to Ajax calls.

I know that issue is due to the application name is added to url (`localhost:8080/applicationame/jspPage`)when I deploy to tomcat server but in development time my url was (`localhost:8080/jspPage`),

I dont see this problem with my old pages,I am experiencing to only to newly added pages

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: You'll have to fix the bug in your code. Since you didn't post anything, that's all we can say.

Comment: @JB yes you are correct error was in code only.